# Does the HT73xx LDO regulator series have reverse polarity protection?

Tags: ldo, reverse-polarity

I can't find in the specs if the [HT73xx series](https://www.holtek.com/productdetail/-/vg/73xx) has any kind of built-in protection against reverse input polarity. What happens if I feed it -10 V instead of +10 V?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *What happens if I feed it -10 V instead of +10 V?*

You will find this in the [data sheet](https://www.holtek.com/documents/10179/116711/HT73xxv180.pdf): -

[image]

Basically any input voltage more negative than -0.3 volts will potentially cause it damage and, in my experience, -10 volts will likely damage it.

Comment: Reverse protection in an LDO is not trivial to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Most LDOs don’t have reverse polarity protection. Those that do use it as a marketable feature and will list it first thing at the top of the datasheet. And in all cases, the Absolute Maximum Ratings section will always answer your question. Devices with reverse polarity protection will be rated for negative voltages on the input!